# Whats this (plastic?) piece hanging on the bottom of my car?

Tags: car

I bought a used opel corsa last week and just noticed today a (pastic?) piece hanging off of the bottom of it. It doesn't look like it was screwed to the car (no holes or anything which would fit a screw) so it seems like its just "sticked in" there somewhere and come loose. There is another one on the other side which looks like its still in place.

Please see the picture:
[image: hanging plastic piece]

Whats this, is it important, how do I reattach it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those flaps weren't there, the airflow underneath the car would hit the rear tires and introduce a certain amount of drag. The manufacturers put those flap there as a wind break.

If you took them off, you wouldn't notice a difference driving around town but if you were on the freeway travelling high speed and for a decent distance, then you might notice fuel economy suffers. How much they actually make a difference though? No idea, the manufacturers don't publish that information.

To reattach that loose one though? Its hard to see detail but I would guess that if you can't see a hole, which would suggest a missing screw, then the mount most likely has broken.

Looking at the location of the flaps, I could imagine them being scraped when going over some speed humps so can be damaged easily.